# How to fix your minecraft launcher when it turns gray and crashes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

Lets say that when you open your Minecraft Launcher you don't see anything and it is all gray. When you click on the launcher it says it is no longer responding and crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Step 1

*Go to your [Minecraft data](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035131551) folder.*

**Windows:** Press <kbd>Win</kbd> (Windows Key) + <kbd>R</kbd>. When you see a box pop up, type in `%appdata%` then press enter. You will then see a folder pop up. Find the folder called `.minecraft`.
**Linux/Mac**: Refer to [this article](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035131551).

#### Step 2

*Reset your .minecraft folder*

Once you see your `.minecraft` folder, right click it and select `Rename`. Rename it to `minecraft_backup`. Please note that this will reset your settings, texture packs and worlds. To bring back your worlds, move the `saves` folder from the `minecraft_backup` folder to the new `.minecraft` folder.

Comment: i see you're still trying with the q&a's, is it OK if i edit this to work with not opening as well?  The fix is different.  Deleting webcache, etc

Comment: @valkyrie_pilot I mean like, isn't the fix resetting the .minecraft folder? Thats what I was told in MDST discord.

Comment: yes it is, please fix