# My Minecraft launcher wont open

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

So I play Minecraft on a Windows 10 PC, and every time I try to open it, the screen will stay grey and it won't respond. I re-installed it, but that didn't work. Then I went into my .minecraft folder and saw that my launcher_profiles.json was gone. These are the Minecraft profiles, right? I think that's the problem, but I don't know how to get it back. How do I get Minecraft to start again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix your minecraft launcher when it turns gray and crashes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380085/how-to-fix-your-minecraft-launcher-when-it-turns-gray-and-crashes)